# Detect if a given binary number belongs to a certain subset with an unitary transformation

Tags: unitarity, matrix-representation

I want to create an operator $A$ which, given three binary numbers, $a_1$, $a_2,a_3$, will detect whether $a_1a_2a_3$ (as a binary number) is in certain set of numbers (for example, detect whether $a_1a_2a_3$ is any integer number between 3 and 5, or if it is an odd number, etc). For that I introduce an ancilla qubit, which will be 1 if $a_1a_2a_3$ is in the desired interval and 0 otherwhise. It is easy to build up the matrix of such linear operator, but it has of course linearly dependent columns. Is there away to express this "detection operation" in terms of unitary transformations, possibly adding more ancillary qubits?
For example, I would have $q_0,q_1,q_2,$ these are the qubits where all the relevant info for the information is contained (the binary number $a_1a_2a_3$), I would then add $q_3$, the qubit that yields the output (1 if $a_1a_2a_3$ is in the desired subset of numbers) and then some other qubits $q_4,\cdots$ which transform in some way so as to make the overall transformation unitary. I have tried with up to two auxiliary qubits, but I always get a singular matrix.

Comment: What about the matrix that sends $|x\rangle|y\rangle$ to $|x\rangle|y\oplus (x\in S)\rangle$? It's unitary since it's a permutation matrix (this is the way we usually define arbitrary functions in QC).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I am sorry I do not understand the notation you used. Could you be more specific?

Comment: $\oplus$ is the exclusive OR. $y$ represents a single subit here. For instance, if you want to represent odd numbers, you would perform a CNOT on the ancilla qubit controlled off the input register's last qubit. That is, you perform a bit flip on the ancilla register if the input register satisfies your condition. You then only have to start with an ancilla initialized to zero and you'll be good to go. Don't hesitate to tell me if that's not clear!

Comment: Thanks! Sorry, I must be a bit dense, but there's still something I don't get. Say that I want to detect if a given binary vector $x$ (of arbitrary length) is in subset $S$. I want another binary variable $y$ to be 1 if $x \in S$ and 0 otherwise. However, given a certain $x \in S$, this operation sends both $x \otimes \vert 0 \rangle $ and $x \otimes \vert 1 \rangle $ to $x \otimes \vert 1 \rangle $, so that the square matrix that represents this operator is singular. I know I must be missing the point, but I do not get it.

Comment: Generally, you can assume that your ancilla is in state $|0\rangle$, which is why the XOR operation works for this case. If you can't assume it, you should add a little more details to describe what you want to do!